# Sencha Touch 2 Web App NOT loading on BlackBerry Torch

Tags: blackberry, touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have deployed a web app, which works fine in iOS, but on Blackberry Torch, the website does NOT even load. Displays a light yellow screen.

I have tried on Blackberry Bold, where the site shows up BUT you cannot interact with the Buttons.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details about the application?  It sounds like that your application has some thing that is not supported by the BB OS 6 platform ( That is why it is not loading on 9800)  But If it works on 9900, then the buttons should be responsive.

Is it a browser application?

Thanks

Naveen M